# Ubuntu goes to black screen on live USB boot

Tags: boot, amdgpu

I have a custom built desktop with a Ryzen 1800x CPU and Radeon RX 580 GPU. Ubuntu has been working perfectly fine on this desktop until recently. I went to live boot 19.04 (after I had issues with my current install) but I am met with a black screen on boot. I went back and tried again with safe graphics enabled and it worked perfectly. However, after I installed it, I now have the same issue I had when I initially tried the live USB. I checked the integrity of the .iso and I have tried multiple different distros (Ubuntu, Manjaro, Clear, and Fedora). I am familiar with issues like this happening with Nvidia cards, but I have never had an issue with my AMD card on Linux.
Any ideas? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: To add to this, I just took an old HD out of my previous desktop with a version of Solus from 2017. This booted without issue. I'm perplexed as to why I am all of the sudden having issues :/

Comment: Unless the computer is new, the LTS releases are often more reliable (debugged and polished for a long time unless when they are new). I suggest that you try with Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS with the 4.15 kernel series.

Comment: sudodus, thanks for the comment! I was actually able to get Ubuntu running again by chrooting and updating the newly installed system from the live USB. That worked! I am now able to boot into Ubuntu :)